# averaging a column in a dataset based on value in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, average

I have a dataframe of a fleet of automobiles of many different models.  Each vehicle is a row including the make, model, and average daily mileage for each particular vehicle.  I am trying to get the average daily mileage by model.  How would I do that?  The actual table has many different models and makes and I do not want to break them out into separate dataframes.  I am sure I can do it with one command in R.  Thank you ahead of time for your help.

Here is an subset of the dataframe 
make    model   mi_per_day 
Hyundai Accent  43
Hyundai Accent  37
Hyundai Genesis 32
Hyundai Genesis 63
Honda   Accord  24
Honda   Accord  54
Honda   Civic   71
Honda   Civic   16
Toyota  Camry   61
Toyota  Camry   27
Toyota  Camry   12

Comment: Hi, can you provide some example data or a reproducible example?

Comment: The [`aggregate`](http://www.statmethods.net/management/aggregate.html) function could be of use

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data look something like :

```
"","make","model","mi_per_day"
"1","Hyundai ","Accent",43
"2","Hyundai ","Genesis",32
"3","Hyundai ","Genesis",63
"4","Honda","Accord",24
"5","Honda","Accord",54
"6","Honda","Civic",71
"7","Honda","Civic",16
"8","Toyota","Camry",61
"9","Toyota","Camry",27
"10","Toyota","Camry",12
```

You could use the following to code:

```
read.csv("/path/to/csv/dir/cars.csv")
aggregate(x = cars$mi_per_day,by=list(cars$make),FUN=mean)
```

This gives the following output:

```
Group.1        x
1  Accent 43.00000
2  Accord 39.00000
3   Camry 33.33333
4   Civic 43.50000
5 Genesis 47.50000
```

Comment: Bouncyball and hhh thank you for repsonding and Bouncyball your answer is awesome

Answer (score 0):

This type of question (need to calculate something by a grouping variable) gets asked a lot on StackOverflow. I decided to show a few different ways of getting the (nearly) same result.

#### Data

First I generated some simple data:

```
set.seed(123)

dat <- data.frame(group = sample(c('a','b','c'), 100, T),
                  value = rnorm(100),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(dat) 

#   group       value
# 1     a  0.25331851
# 2     c -0.02854676
# 3     b -0.04287046
# 4     c  1.36860228
# 5     c -0.22577099
# 6     a  1.51647060
```

#### Aggregation examples

I'm going to look at some different ways of performing the aggregation: [`by`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/by.html), [`aggregate`](http://www.statmethods.net/management/aggregate.html), [`lapply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) and [`split`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/split.html), [`tapply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/tapply.html), [**`dplyr`**](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html), and [**`data.table`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html).

To use the `by` function, we pass in some `data`, and give it the variable we want to group by, then we pass the function we want applied, then I use `stack` to get it in tabular form.

```
stack(by(dat, dat$group, function(d) mean(d$value)))

#        values ind
# 1  0.05444944   a
# 2 -0.16894993   b
# 3 -0.04324673   c
```

To use the `aggregate` function, we can use a formula syntax, and give it our data and the function we want. I like `aggregate` a lot.

```
aggregate(value ~ group, data = dat, mean)

#   group       value
# 1     a  0.05444944
# 2     b -0.16894993
# 3     c -0.04324673
```

We can use `split` and `lapply` to first separate the data by our grouping variable, and then perform a calculation on the separated list. We use `stack` to put the result in a tabular form.

```
stack(lapply(split(dat, dat$group), function(d) mean(d$value)))

#        values ind
# 1  0.05444944   a
# 2 -0.16894993   b
# 3 -0.04324673   c
```

We can use the `tapply` function to apply a function over a ragged array. We give it our variable we want to use for calculation, our grouping variable, and our function. We use `stack` to put the result in a tabular form.

```
stack(tapply(dat$value, dat$group, mean))

#        values ind
# 1  0.05444944   a
# 2 -0.16894993   b
# 3 -0.04324673   c
```

We can use the excellent **`dplyr`** package to perform the aggregation as well. We first group the data using `group_by`, and then apply our function using `summarise`. The `%>%` symbols are pipes - and they're super useful.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(mean(value))

#   group `mean(value)`
#   <chr>         <dbl>
# 1     a    0.05444944
# 2     b   -0.16894993
# 3     c   -0.04324673
```

Finally, we can use the performant **`data.table`** package to perform the aggregation. The syntax might look a little strange at first, but we're basically saying: calculate the mean value grouped by group.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[,mean(value),group]

#    group          V1
# 1:     a  0.05444944
# 2:     c -0.04324673
# 3:     b -0.16894993
```